# CryptoPP project running on another computer

Tags: c++, encryption, visual-studio-2017, crypto++

I wrote a small console application in Visual Studio Community 2017 using c++ language and crypto++ library to encrypt and decrypt some data from user. I want encrypt some data on computer(for example .txt file), transfer it to another computer and there decrypt the data using my program that I wrote. So my question is: Can I save this project and create a .exe file and running it on another computer, in console enter the secret key and decrypt data?
Thank for any help!

Comment: Yes, have you tried it? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @AlanBirtles In folder debug I have a executable file, but it's work only on my computer, in folder where I have all files with crypto++ etc. I try publish project but I don't have this option in my project. What I should do?

Comment: Debug versions of MSVC DLLs are not redistributable. To run your executable on another computer without Visual Studio installed, make sure to build the **Release** (not Debug) executable. The other computer will then only need to install the [Visual C++ Redistributable package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) (for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 & 2019). Another option is to link your executable *statically* (not dynamically) to MSVC runtimes. In that case, it will not require MSVC redistributable DLLs to run, even on another PC.

Comment: @heapunderrun I tried to run this in Release mode, but the file size is 500[kB], less than debug exe file which is 4000[kB]. And when i run this program starting .exe file It dosen't work. I don't where I did a mistake

Comment: @szczepan19 it is normal that the release version is smaller as the compiler optimized your code. The program not working is very likely due to a bug in your code that doesn't manifest itself in debug mode.

Comment: If you've linked against the crypto++ dll you'll need to copy the dll your second machine too

Comment: I had a small error in my code so thats why my program did not work but now it's work. I have another question.
In folder where I have my project in Release version I have 4 files with this extensions:
`Encrypt.exe, Encrypt.iobj, Encrypt.ipdb, Encrypt.pdb.` It's work but my question is: Can I get a one exe file without another files to run it?

Comment: @szczepan19 The `*.iobj` and `*.ipdb` files are used to speed up code generation during linking; the `*.pdb` file is so-called _program database_ used for debugging and crash dump analysis. None of these files are needed to run the executable (`*.exe`).

Comment: @heapunderrun You are right. it works! Thanks!!